# How do I implement this basic CSS for just one category?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm a newbie but I can follow clear instructions. I tried searching for this problem and I can't seem to find a solution.

I have just two types of (main) category on my WordPress site: Quotes and Articles.  That's all. Each one has their own subcategories. (about 100 or so)

I want to style one of them (the "Quotes" category) and all its sub-categories this way:

```
.post-title {display:none;}
h2.post-box-title {display: none;}
.page-title {display:none;}
a.more-link { display: none;}
```

If I do that that from Global CSS in my theme, it applies to everything on site which isn't what I want. I want the other main category (Articles) and all its subcategories to not be affected by that CSS, so what do I do?

I read that the function would be something like:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 'Quotes' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 'Quotes' ) )
```

but how and where and what to do I don't understand.

Comment: depending on the theme, there might be built in post classes that will help you solve this. Please use inspect to see if one (or all) of the posts in question has the class of `quotes` or `articles`

Comment: You are saying that when a post is being printed on the webpage, if the post belongs to the Quotes category then it should have different CSS than the other categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, That condition might work for you, but only if placed on the right place.

`if ( in_category( 'Quotes' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( id_of_Quotes_category ) )`

When ever a post is printed wordpress creates a  `div`  Block 
What you can basically do is, whenever a post from the quotes category comes. In the  `div`  block of the post add a extra css class, e.g. quotes

so  your code will be like

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if (in_category( 'Quotes' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category('ID_OF_Quotes_Category' ) ) :
?>
    <div class="post quotes">
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="post">
<?php endif; ?>
```

and then your css code will be

```
.quotes .post-title {display:none;}
.quotes h2.post-box-title {display: none;}
.quotes a.more-link { display: none;}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: amit ty but i still am confused. please bear with me, i'm a newbie but i do get instructions.

ok i get what you mean about the code, now my question is where do i inject that...in my functions.php or single.php or category.php?

and as for the css, what do i put that, in the main style.css?

Comment: that depends on your requirement. 
1. you will have to use it in single.php if you want your css to be implemented on the page where you sees the single post.
2. you will have to use it in category.php if you want your css to be implemented on the page where you sees all the post of particular category.
3. you have to use it on content pahe if you want to use it on your blogs home page. 

you don't need to edit your functions.php file

Comment: it will be on category page (archive i think?). because the category itself (when clicked on) is what lists the posts...and its when it's the 'Quotes' (and all subcategories) of it that i want to apply those css styles. for the other category (Article) and all its subcategories, i'm fine with the theme's default.

so ok i will try the code you gave me. does it matter where i put it in the category php or does it have to be in a certain row?

Comment: in other word, i want your option 2.

Comment: Ok then you see the `category.php` file code in your template, if it contains a line like  `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() )` 
if yes, then you have to apply it on content page, otherwise you can place it in category.php file.

And yes it does matter where you place this code. 
it will be better if you read how wordpress loop works, Then it will be easy for you to use the code. 

https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: <div class="post-listing">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <article <?php tie_post_class('item-list'); ?>>
 
  <h2 class="post-box-title">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </h2>
  
  <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/meta-archives' ); ?>     

  <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content( __ti( 'Read More &raquo;' ) ); ?>
  </div>
  
  <?php if( tie_get_option( 'archives_socail' ) ) get_template_part( 'framework/parts/share' );  ?>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </article><!-- .item-list -->

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>

Comment: sorry dont know how to use code here. that's the content-loop. i see that my theme uses that

Comment: long story short, Just replace

`<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> <article <?php tie_post_class('item-list'); ?>>`

with 

`<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if (in_category( 'Quotes' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category('ID_OF_Quotes_Category' ) ) :
?>
    <span class="quotes">
<?php else : ?>
    <span>
<?php endif; ?>
<article <?php tie_post_class('item-list'); ?>>` and also 

Replace  
` </article>` 
with 
 `</article></span>`


and write your css as i told before. 
Just a guess hope it will work

Comment: and also replace `ID_OF_Quotes_Category` with the id of Quotes category.

Comment: i get this:  Fatal error: Call to undefined function post_is_in_descendant_category() in /home/alibam/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/sahifa/framework/loops/loop-content.php on line 8

Comment: `if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
 function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
  foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
   
   $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
   if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
    return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
}` 

write this function in functions.php and check, i think it should work fine.

Comment: Amit, thank you very much. The error is gone. Seems OK.  Now comes the part of the css code, where do i put them? in style.css? And if so, where or how do i define them. 

.post-title {display:none;}
h2.post-box-title {display: none;}
.page-title {display:none;}
a.more-link { display: none;}

Comment: open your style.css file and 

`.quotes .post-title { display:none; }
.quotes h2.post-box-title { display: none; }
.quotes a.more-link { display: none; }`

Comment: Woah, it worked. thank you very, very, very much, sir. I put them same place, GLOBAL CSS in theme, but now i get what you mean...by putting quotes. before them, it applies only to the quotes categories. thank you so much. i really wish i can buy you a beer. :)

Comment: wow, glad it worked and solved your problem, and yeah sure ;)

Comment: Really, thank you so much. You have no idea how much you help me. This problem has been haunting me for months. I'm a newbie so you know it's really hard coming across the right threads and explaining what i want. you got me and helped me. im so grateful realy. thank you so much, Amit.

Comment: its my pleasure sir that my code worked for you. :), Actually helping you was fun because you never gave up. lots of people never do that.

Comment: i only have one last thing but i really don't want to bother you. you've already helped me a lot. just tell me yes or no and i will figure it out on my own.

ok i told you in begining i have two categories only (quotes)+ its subcategories and (articles) + its subcategories. i wanted articles to stay as it is.  and style just quotes with all of its subcategories. that worked.

in reality i have one more. you see, i have Quotes and then its subs are inspirational, life lessons, funny , religious.

but i have another main: quotes by authors and under it like einstein, edison, etc. so question is

Comment: can i still apply the same entry you gave me into the loop for 'quotes by authors'?

Comment: like use two IDs in that in this area:

post_is_in_descendant_category('id of quotes' 'id of quotes by authors' ) )

Comment: yes you can do the same for this too, 
just add an else if block in the code.

`if (in_category( 'Quotes' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category('ID_OF_Quotes_Category' ) ) : ?> <span class="quotes"> 
<?php else if (in_category( 'quotes by authors' ) || post_is_in_descendant_category('ID_OF_quotes_by_authors' ) ) : ?> 
<span class="quotesbyautor"> 
<?php else : ?> <span> <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: you want to use same css for two categories? or Different for quotes and different for Quotes by author.

Comment: yes same css becauuse all these are about quotes but i didnt put 'quotes by authors' as subcategory of 'quotes' becasue it too has its subcategories. i didnt know how to do it when i started so i broke it as follow

Quotes >> inspiritional or life lessons or relationships (you know, type of quotes).    

that is now taken care. (what you helped me with earlier)

Quotes by Authoe >> einstein, edison, etc.

but same css yes

Comment: ok then its quite easy actually, code is fine. Right know what we are doing is passing single values in both function but if we want to run it for multiple categories we have to pass array of it. Like `(in_category(array('quotes','quotes by author')) || post_is_in_descendant_category(array('ID_OF_quotes_by_authors','ID_of_quotes_category' )))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tips to help you:

- You can try to make sure you new styles are at the bottom of the `style.css` page
- You can also right click on your element in google chrome and click Inspect or Inspect Element then right click on you html and click on copy css path or go under copy and and click copy selector like here:
  [image]

hope it helps thank you

Comment: But that would still be doing what it does: applying it to everything. I only want that CSS styling applied to just ONE category (and all its subcategories) which is, in my case, the 'Quotes' Category. As for the only other main category (and its subcategories) which is the 'Articles' category, I want things left as they are, meaning not to apply that CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the discussion on wordpress support , it might be useful to 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-each-category-page-have-its-own-look

Comment: This would be better as a comment.  Answers should provide an explanation in the text body.